# Set new image on imagecopyresampled to be 100% width / height

Tags: php, image

I am using a modified version of http://shanechism.com/code/2011/06/facebook-picture-overlay-script ([demo here](http://serve.shanechism.com/projects/FacebookPicOverlay)) to set a frame around a picture that the user uploads.

However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to set the frame to encompass the entire image (100% width / height), as opposed to appear as a 'watermark' on the bottom-left of the image.

I believe the answer lies in the following line of code:

```
imagecopyresampled( $tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new[0], $new[1],
    $this->uploadedInfo[0], $this->uploadedInfo[1] );
```

Anyone have any ideas? From what I've researched on Stackoverflow & beyond, the answer isn't as straight forward as I'd hope, but I thought I'd ask here just in-case.

Thanks

Comment: Curious why you deleted  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092268/upload-file-to-javascript-and-automatically-apply-image-overlay ? Did you resolve issue? fwiw, composed a possible solution

Comment: I was asking for a little too much. I needed the 2nd image to apply automatically, OVER the 1st image. I wasn't sure of the direction to go with as my JS knowledge is limited, so I went with PHP instead. I left out the download function on purpose, as I was unsure of whether or not it would be allowed on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to provide download functionality at stacksnippets. You were not appending the new image over the `canvas` at `load` event of new `img`.

Comment: I can re-open the question, if you wish. If it's something that you feel can be solved, you may as well receive points for a correct answer. I assume it will help others in the future solve similar issues with JS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m4omup0d/3/

Answer (score 0):

imagecopyresampled works like this

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

You can adjust your function $src_w, $src_h, $dst_w and $dst_h to be your desired width/height for the source/destination

[Full documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)